# Edit a feature/graphic's location using Edit toolbar (javascript 3.20 api)

Tags: editing, feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've loaded a feature layer into a web map (using javascript api 3.20).
I'm trying to use the following to edit an existing points location (by dragging it to a new location) in a feature layer that I have loaded. I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#movebtn', GeomEdit);

function GeomEdit() {
    var editpoint = new Edit(map);
    editpoint.activate(Edit.MOVE, <graphic>).
}
```

This function fires when I click a button WITHIN the infowindow (#movebtn) of the point I clicked.

I am unsure of what I need to put into the graphic parameter to make this work?

What are the requirements?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ed_feature_creation.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are use map.infoWindow, you can access selected graphic this way "map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature()".

note : while you open the infowindow, you must use map.infoWindow.setFeatures([graphic])

so :

```
$(document).on('click', '#movebtn', GeomEdit);

function GeomEdit() {
    var editpoint = new Edit(map);
    editpoint.activate(Edit.MOVE, map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature()).
}
```